# How to run query inside a class with namespace?

Tags: wp-query, oop

I tried to run a query inside a class

this was the structure

```
    namespace NCK{

    class Runquery{
      public function execute(){
      $query= new WP_Query(array(..............));
      return $query;
     }}}
```

But when i used

```
$getvalue = new NCK\Runquery();
var_dump($getvalue->execute());
```

It throws an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'NCK\WP_Query' not found in

is there any way i can make it works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a `\` in front of the `WP_Query` call to tell PHP that it's in the global namespace and not the namespace of this class.

Try this: `$query = new \WP_Query($args);`

Comment: How would you use wp_reset_postdata() afterwards? It appears that it doesn't see the query that way.